# how can I make the password verify function work with $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, password-hash

I want to make an login system with password verify. I have encrypted my password with password default. I also stored the hash in the database. Now I want to use password verify to make an login system, but the function always reteruns a value of true. can someone explains why? And can someone explain me how I can use password verify with $_POST?

code for the hash

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: jbosma
 * Date: 24/07/2018
 * Time: 23:21
 */
include_once "dbconnection.php";
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) { // send the input
    $username = $_POST["username"]; // post the input username
    $password = $_POST["password"]; // post the input password
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=loginapp", $user, $pass); // database connection
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // error mode
    $hash = PASSWORD_HASH($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // make $hash so you can give that to your password in the query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('".$username."','".$hash."')"; // insert the username and the password that will be hashed
    $conn->exec($sql); // excecute the query above
    header('location: register.php'); // after you submit it redirects to login.php




}
```

code for password verify

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: jbosma
 * Date: 27/07/2018
 * Time: 12:11
 */
include_once "dbconnection.php";
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) { // send the input
    $username = $_POST["username"]; // post the input username
    $password = $_POST["password"]; // post the input password

    $hash = $password; // hash from password
    if (password_verify($_POST["password"], $hash)) {
        echo "Welcome";
    } else {
        echo "Wrong Password";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `$hash = $password = $_POST['password']` meaning you are sending the user input twice to `password_verify`.

Comment: The HASHED password was written to the database, get it back from there. `password_verify()` compares a plain text string to the HASHED password for you, but you still have to go and get it from the database or whereever you stored it

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't ever return a value of true, let alone "always"

Comment: While PHP is (annoyingly) case insensitive, this is not license to arbitrarily switch the case on function calls. Try and use the form as documented.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. You do not want to waste six months writing and testing a login system that's *actually* secure, and that's only possible if you've already spent years learning about all the threat vectors.

Comment: @tadman Can someone use the authentication module of Laravel without using the framework?

Comment: @dakis There are stand-alone authentication-only frameworks like [Auth0](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-PHP). Laravel comes as a feature-complete package, but I think some components, like Eloquent, can be used stand-alone.

Comment: @tadman Thanks. If I may, I would suggest to advice just for using specific standalone libraries. The use of a framework, or even of an MVC architecture, is not of relevance in this context.

Comment: @dakis It absolutely is. If you're not using a framework you're responsible for a whole lot of things that are difficult, annoying, and if not done perfectly, quick to become a huge liability. XSS is no joke. CSRF will destroy you. A good framework will give you a layer of security and patterns for writing secure code that, if followed, make your application very difficult to compromise. Your hand-rolled code offers no such guarantee.

Comment: @tadman I am just saying, that you don't have to couple your application (be it even an MVC one) to a whole framework, in order to use its security module. You can develop an application in such a way, that it uses the security component from Symfony, the routing component from FastRoute, the PHP-DI DIC, and so on.

Comment: @dakis Those are other good examples. You can make your own composite application, but I wouldn't recommend this for beginners.

Comment: @tadman I understand and respect your point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Have something like this in your reg form, it's using BCRYPT in this instance. This is just showing the password_hash function

**Register**

```
// Other code  leading up to this..
....
//
$passHash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 12));


  $insrt = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($insrt);


  $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
  $stmt->bindValue(':password', $passHash);


  $result = $stmt->execute();

  if($result){
// Do whatever you want
```

**login**

```
// Other code  leading up to this..
....
//
$validPassword = password_verify($pass, $user['password']);

    if($validPassword){

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['username'];
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = time();

        // redirects in this case
        header( "Location: /wherever.php" );
        die();

    } else{
        die('Wrong password!');
    }
```

This is just showing how to use the functions themselves, apply this principle and you should be good to go

Comment: While this code is a huge improvement on the original, it's still extremely risky to use this code in a production environment. I'd **strongly discourage** exposing actual users to this code.

Comment: Yeah was thrown together in about 5 seconds, just thought it'd be easier than trying to salvage something out of what he had written. Thank you though, any links you could give me to help improve it? always love making things more secure

Comment: Sadly, sometimes it's best to let the patient die than to have this code go on and cause severe damage. The problem with this code is primarily that it's 1% of what you need to do to make a secure application. What about CSRF? XSS? What about OAuth support? What about a proper MVC layer? None of those things are here, and adding them, with rigorous testing, would take years even for someone with considerable experience. This stuff is *hard*. That's why frameworks exist.

Comment: I think it's great you're trying to help. I'm just concerned that code like this that's "fixed" gives people a false sense of security. It's like giving an amateur pointers on how to wash their hands and what scalpel to use before doing open-heart surgery for the first time. The risks are extremely high these days even for the most trivial and obscure of sites.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem**

Your `password_verify` returns always `true` because, by using `password_verify($_POST["password"], $hash)`, you are actually comparing `$_POST["password"]` with itself - since `$hash = $password` and `$password = $_POST["password"]`.

**The solution**

The `password_verify` should compare the posted password (`$_POST["password"]`) with the password hash, which has to be fetched from the database, first. So your login code should look something like this:

```
<?php
include_once "dbconnection.php";

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $sql = "SELECT password FROM users where username = '" . $username . "' LIMIT 1";
    $statement = $conn->query($sql);
    $credentials = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($credentials) { // Record found.
        $hash = $credentials['password'];

        // Compare the posted password with the password hash fetched from db.
        if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
            echo "Welcome";
        } else {
            echo "Wrong Password";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No credentials found for the given user.';
    }
}
```

Note that this solution is opened to [sql injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use prepared statements instead (see the extended example bellow).

---

**Another, extended example:**

Here is another example of using the `password_hash - password_verify` tandem. Though I agree with @tadman: you should make use of external libraries - offered as part of a framework of your wish, or as standalone components - providing a solide security layer.

Note that the first important step in avoiding the so-called sql injections and, more specifically, in assuring a secure authentication/authorization system, is the use of [prepared statements](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared). Try to always apply this preparation step when you are working with a data access layer.

**register.php**

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

// Signalize if a new account could be created, or not.
$accountCreated = FALSE;

/*
 * ================================
 * Operations upon form submission.
 * ================================
 */
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    /*
     * =======================
     * Read the posted values.
     * =======================
     */
    $username = $_POST['username'] ?? '';
    $password = $_POST['password'] ?? '';

    /*
     * ===========================
     * Validate the posted values.
     * ===========================
     */
    // Validate the username.
    if (empty($username)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide a username.';
    } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

    // Validate the password.
    if (empty($password)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide a password.';
    } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

    /*
     * ==================================
     * Check if user exists. Save if not.
     * ==================================
     */
    if (!isset($errors)) {
        /*
         * =============================
         * Check if user already exists.
         * =============================
         */

        /*
         * The SQL statement to be prepared. Notice the so-called named markers.
         * They will be replaced later with the corresponding values from the
         * bindings array when using PDOStatement::bindValue.
         *
         * When using named markers, the bindings array will be an associative
         * array, with the key names corresponding to the named markers from
         * the sql statement.
         *
         * You can also use question mark markers. In this case, the bindings
         * array will be an indexed array, with keys beginning from 1 (not 0).
         * Each array key corresponds to the position of the marker in the sql
         * statement.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
         */
        $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM users
                WHERE username = :username';

        /*
         * The bindings array, mapping the named markers from the sql
         * statement to the corresponding values. It will be directly
         * passed as argument to the PDOStatement::execute method.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php
         */
        $bindings = [
            ':username' => $username,
        ];

        /*
         * Prepare the sql statement for execution and return a statement object.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
         */
        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

        /*
         * Execute the prepared statement. Because the bindings array
         * is directly passed as argument, there is no need to use any
         * binding method for each sql statement's marker (like
         * PDOStatement::bindParam or PDOStatement::bindValue).
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php
         */
        $statement->execute($bindings);

        /*
         * Fetch the data and save it into a variable.
         *
         * @link https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php
         */
        $numberOfFoundUsers = $statement->fetchColumn(0);

        if ($numberOfFoundUsers > 0) {
            $errors[] = 'The given username already exists. Please choose another one.';
        } else {
            /*
             * ========================
             * Save a new user account.
             * ========================
             */
            // Create a password hash.
            $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

            $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (
                        username,
                        password
                    ) VALUES (
                        :username,
                        :password
                    )';

            $bindings = [
                ':username' => $username,
                ':password' => $passwordHash,
            ];

            $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute($bindings);

            // Signalize that a new account was successfully created.
            $accountCreated = TRUE;

            // Reset all values so that they are not shown in the form anymore.
            $username = $password = NULL;
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo - Register</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            .messages { margin-bottom: 10px; }
            .messages a { text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 700;}
            .error, .success { margin-bottom: 5px; }
            .error { color: #ff0000; }
            .success { color: #32cd32; }
            .form-group { margin-bottom: 10px; }
            .form-group label { display: inline-block; min-width: 90px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h3>
            Register
        </h3>

        <div class="messages">
            <?php
            if (isset($errors)) {
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="error">
                        <?php echo $error; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            } elseif ($accountCreated) {
                ?>
                <div class="success">
                    You have successfully created your account.
                    <br/>Would you like to <a href="login.php">login</a> now?
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <form action="" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo $username ?? ''; ?>" placeholder="Username">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password ?? ''; ?>" placeholder="Password">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" id="registerButton" name="submit" value="register">
                Register
            </button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

/*
 * ================================
 * Operations upon form submission.
 * ================================
 */
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    /*
     * =======================
     * Read the posted values.
     * =======================
     */
    $username = $_POST['username'] ?? '';
    $password = $_POST['password'] ?? '';

    /*
     * ===========================
     * Validate the posted values.
     * ===========================
     */
    // Validate the username.
    if (empty($username)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide a username.';
    } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

    // Validate the password.
    if (empty($password)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide a password.';
    } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

    /*
     * ======================
     * Check the credentials.
     * ======================
     */
    if (!isset($errors)) { // No errors yet.
        $sql = 'SELECT username, password
                FROM users
                WHERE username = :username
                LIMIT 1';

        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

        $statement->execute([
            ':username' => $username,
        ]);

        /*
         * Fetch the credentials into an associative array.
         * If no record is found, the operation returns FALSE.
         */
        $credentials = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($credentials) { // Record found.
            $fetchedUsername = $credentials['username'];
            $fetchedPasswordHash = $credentials['password'];

            /*
             * Compare the posted username with the one saved in db and the posted
             * password with the password hash saved in db using password_hash.
             *
             * @link https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
             * @link https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
             */
            if (
                    $username === $fetchedUsername &&
                    password_verify($password, $fetchedPasswordHash)
            ) {
                header('Location: welcome.html');
                exit();
            } else {
                $errors[] = 'Invalid credentials. Please try again.';
            }
        } else {
            $errors[] = 'No credentials found for the given user.';
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo - Login</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validateForm() {
                // ...Some form validation, if needed...
                return true;
            }
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .messages { margin-bottom: 10px; }
            .error { margin-bottom: 5px; color: #ff0000; }
            .form-group { margin-bottom: 10px; }
            .form-group label { display: inline-block; min-width: 90px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h3>
            Login
        </h3>

        <div class="messages">
            <?php
            if (isset($errors)) {
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="error">
                        <?php echo $error; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo $username ?? ''; ?>" placeholder="Username">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password ?? ''; ?>" placeholder="Password">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" id="loginButton" name="submit" value="login">
                Login
            </button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php

/*
 * This page contains the code for creating a PDO connection instance.
 */

// Db configs.
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'tests');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', 'root');
define('CHARSET', 'utf8');

$connection = new PDO(
        sprintf('mysql:host=%s;port=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s', HOST, PORT, DATABASE, CHARSET)
        , USERNAME
        , PASSWORD
        , [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        ]
);
```

**welcome.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo - Welcome</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h3>
            Welcome
        </h3>

        <div>
            Hi. You are now logged-in.
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Table definition**

Notice the length of 255 characters of the `password` column. The field should be (at least) so long. More details at [password_hash](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) (in *"Description"*).

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```